# Downgrading Nexus 7 Android 4.4.2 to 4.2

Tags: nexus-7, downgrade

I want to downgrade my nexus 7 android 4.4.2 to 4.2. I am already rooted. How can i downgrade? I've got a nandroid backup. If I restore that will it be again running as android 4.4.2?

I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you downgrade, you will need to re-root it again.

If you are confident in flashing and using Google's `adb` and `fastboot` tools, then could point you to the direction of [Google Factory Images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) for the Nexus.

Be aware of the differing versions available, flashing the wrong one could end up messing the device and having to re-do the flash again.

You will have to identify it, it would be shown on the bootloader screen, and pick the appropriate version, there's the 2012 model, 2013 model with variations of WiFi, one with 3G+WiFi and another with LTE.